# the summation of multiple sums

Tags: summation

I have a problem where I need to formalize the following summation

$\sum_{i=1}^k ni $ + $\sum_{i=1}^k ni $ + $\sum_{i=1}^k ni$ + ... 
the sum will be repeted m times and the k values will be different in each summation notation.

Comment: So you mean $\sum_{j=1}^m  \sum_{i=1}^k n^{(j)}_i$ where the upper index indicates the different summation values? Or written in your way: $ \sum_{i=1}^k n^{(1)}_i + \sum_{i=1}^k n^{(2)}_i + \ldots + \sum_{i=1}^k n^{(m)}_i$?

Comment: i don't think so, see every series has different values, as example i need to calculate the following { (3)  + ( 4+2+6) + (7+1+3))} m=3 k= 1,3,3

Answer (score 1):

Since there are $m$ sums $S_i,1\leq i\leq m$, we can write
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^mS_i\qquad\qquad\qquad &m\geq 1
\end{align*}

Each sum $S_i$ contains $k_i$ summands $n_{i,j},1\leq j\leq k_i$
\begin{align*}
S_i=\sum_{j=1}^{k_i} n_{i,j}\qquad\qquad\quad 1\leq i\leq m
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^mS_i=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^{k_i}n_{i,j}\qquad\qquad m\geq 1
> \end{align*}